# Is there a way to record how many time applications are running in the foreground?

Tags: command-line, window, process

And eventually also when they are started and closed and how many time they have been running in the background and in the foreground.

I don't need that for every single app, but only for a few. I may use a custom launcher from a desktop file (but how?). But since I have a dozen apps to track, a general solution would be better.

Thanks in advance !!

**Edit** : I call foreground when a window has the focus.

Comment: I don't think that "fore-" and "back-" ground is so clear for a desktop. I have now three apps (firefox, a mail reader, and a text editor) opened side by side in my two screens, and they are run a few milliseconds each to give the impression on running together. Are they foreground, one third foreground, or what? Is the notification tray along the border of the desktop a foreground or background app?

Comment: Oh. I meant foreground like when the window has the focus. If there's no focus, that's background (in my sight of view), even if, technically, the app has a window on the screen. But you are right, that may be hard to distinguish for the machine. How do I check by command line which application has the focus ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any out of box solution.

If you're running X Window, you might easily write a shell script based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017988/4457671). You'd have a loop where you run `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`, cut out the window id from that, then pass it to `xprop -id ...`, process its output (e.g. `grep` for a few relevant keys) and store it somewhere (e.g. append to a text file). Finally, `sleep` for maybe 10 seconds in the loop.

Meanwhile, write some scripts that process the log files (or upload that to a database, etc.).

Such approach cannot work under Wayland due to its security model, I'm afraid there you would need to hack the compositor to do this logging for you.

Answer (score 0):

To check [which windows has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014822/how-to-know-which-window-has-focus-and-how-to-change-it) you can run this in a terminal:

```
[romano:~] 3s 130 % while true; do
xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 
sleep 3
done
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x3600006
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x3a00010
```

(Notice that if you give the command `xprop...` while typing, you'll obviously have the ID of the terminal window in which you are typing...)

Then you can see the [PID of the process owning the window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window) with:

```
[romano:~] % xprop -id 0x3a00010 _NET_WM_PID
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 18522
```

...and then search the process [with any of the `ps` tools](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name).

```
[romano:~] % ps  -p 18522  
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18522 ?        00:04:55 firefox
```

Notice that this works with X11 --- no idea about Wayland.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That is indeed more or less what I was looking for. Still, I am using Wayland, so I would prefer a Wayland solution, but I could consider to change and use Xorg in the first place. But I'll better find a Wayland solution (which may be similar to this one) if possible.